# If + future tense

Tags: conditionals

Would you please explain the grammar for (and the meaning of) the structure 'if + future tense' in the following two examples:

> ***If*** she ***will*** not provide consent, then you should consider whether you are able to continue to act without placing you in breach of any of the mandatory Principles.
>
> You would need to cease to act ***if*** client ***will*** not allow the document to be included on the list.

Based on what I was taught during my English lessons, a clause like 'if' will never have the future tense.

The examples do not follow what I was told. I encounter these structures very often, but I cannot explain the structure to myself and I am not sure whether I understand them correctly.

Kind regards,

Comment: It should be *without placing **yourself** in breach . . .* (And it's odd to see *Principles* with a capital *P*, although it might make sense in context.) That aside, there's nothing wrong with the sentence. I know of no such rule (or convention) that you indicate.

Comment: Many thanks for spotting mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The statement that " a clause like 'if' will never have the future tense." is simply not correct. The example sentences are expressing a future conditional.

In the first sentence, whether she will (in the future) provide consent is not yet known. But if consent is not provided, then the speaker instructs the listener to "consider whether you are able to continue to act..."

In the second sentence, the future condition is whether the client will allow the document to be included on the list. It is not yet know if this condition will be true or not. But if it does not become true, the listener is instructed to cease to act [for the client].

In short such a construction expresses an uncertain or undecided possibility in the future, and action to follow one possible outcome.

> If you will not finish your degree, you will not get the job you want.

This could also be "do not' instead of will not. The 'will not" form emphasizes that this is a choice.

> If he exercises more, his muscle tome will improve.
>
> If he does more of the yard work, he will spend less on the lawn service.
>
> If he will get up earlier, his days will go more smoothly.

In general: If + future expression + future consequence